# JQuery Clone () Issue. A simple program to clone a block of code is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner in this field. 
I created a HTML page and on the click of some "+"/"-" buttons I am calling add() and remove() respectively from Multiple.js file to add or remove a block of code from the HTML page. But I am getting unexpected results. The files are as follow:
Multiple Group Selection.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<TITLE>Multiple Group Selections</TITLE>
<script src="Multiple.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">
<H2 ALIGN="CENTER">Multiple Group Selections</H2>
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
<FIELDSET class="field">
<LEGEND ALIGN="RIGHT">
<button type="button" class = "clone" onclick={add();}  >+</button>
<button type="button" class = "remove" onclick={remove();}>-</button>
</LEGEND>
Field 2A: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="field2A" VALUE="Field A"><BR>
Field 2B: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="field2B" VALUE="Field B"><BR>
Field 2C: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="field2C" VALUE="Field C"><BR>
</FIELDSET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Multiple.js:

```
function add(){
var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

$("button.clone").live("click", function(){
$(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
    .find("*").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
        }
});
cloneIndex++;
});

}
function remove(){
 $("button.remove").live("click", function(){
 $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
});
}
```

style.css

```
 .clone {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 12px;  
 font-weight: bold; 
 color: #00ffff;
 Background-COLOR: white;
 border: black;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 }
.remove{
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 12px; 
font-weight: bold; 
color: #00ffff;
Background-COLOR: white;
border: black;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

All I want is at the click of "+" button the  must be appended to the . At the click of "-" button it should be removed as well. Please help me out. I am exhausted.

Comment: Create a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AJxLn/3/) is a jsfiddle for whoever is answering this.

Comment: The numbering scheme is unsustainable. It is possible to introduce duplicate ids simply by removing elements from the top and adding more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one place you are definitely going astray is trying to mix inline `onclick` handlers with unobtrusive jquery click handlers. Especially when they are both click handlers for same element. If you are just starting up, and going to work with jQuery the best approach would be to not use any inline javascript at all.

Reading your `add()` function you have to click on the add button, which then creates a jQuery clcik handler... but the click has already occured, so that handler won't fire the first time.

Stripping out the inline `onclick` and unwrapping the `add()` and `remove()` functions takes all the javascript out of the markup and makes it easier to follow.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfg7P/

Note: fieldset should be inside form tag , there is no form tag in markup.

Comment: @Asad does bring up a good point that I thought about also. When you remove a row, your ID index can get duplicated.

Comment: please try not take it personally, but unlike my answer, you get duplicated `id`, and that shouldnt happen. here, i updated your code to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/Xfg7P/2/

Comment: @RASG   understood, I felt it was important to spend time explaining to someone new to JS where their approach was going off track. Simply providing code doesn't always help teach. The best answers aren't always about code alone

Comment: i didnt realize he was new to JS, since he was using `regex` and a JS library. but you're right. it is more important to explain what is happening than just show the code and expect him to understand. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

i simplified your function that clones the elements and add a new dynamic `id`.

```
$('#btnclone').on('click', function() {
    var lastid = $('[id^="clonedInput"]').length + 1;
    $(".clonedInput")
        .last()
        .clone()
        .attr('id', 'clonedInput' + lastid)
        .appendTo("body")
    $('input').each(function() {
        $(this).val('PARENT DIV ID =  ' + $(this).parent().attr('id'))
    })
})
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/MjMh5/